# JVM Memory usage patter issue

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I recently configured one JBOSS application with application monitoring tools (StatsD) which helps to capture JVM utilization of the application. Even without any single users using the application, the memory pattern touches around 90-95% (850 - 970 MB)of the allocated memory (1024 MB).
Minor GC runs at every point when the memory reaches 90-95%. Please see the below screenshot for the same.

Request your help to know what can be the reason/s for such a memory pattern.
*No batch jobs or background process is running.

[image]

Comment: you may start taking a heap dump and analyze which are the biggest objects. Myabe the footprint is high, and the server needs more memory

Comment: @devwebcl : I took the heap dump for the application and analyzed it. But I got an issue here too where the heap dump says it is of ~1GB but when I upload it on Eclipse MAT, it only shows the dump of 11MB. Most of the heavy objects are seen under "unreached objects" section of MAT.
Please let me know why a 1GB dump is only showing 11MB size in MAT if you have any idea or have used MAT for analysis.

Comment: it's strange that snows only 11mb. Could it be an object of 11mb ? Can you upload a screenshot of Eclipse MAT ?

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like normal behavior to me.  The heap space used rises gradually  to a point where a GC runs.  Then the GC reclaims a lot of free space and the heap space used drops steeply.  Then repeat.

It looks like you have stats from two separate JVMs in the same graph, but I guess you knew that.  (You have obscured the labels on the graph that could explain that.)

The only other thing I can glean from this is that the memory allocation rate is on the high side to be causing the GC to run that frequently.  It may be advisable to do some GC tuning.  But I would only advise that if application-level performance was suffering.  (And it may well be that the real problem was application efficiency rather than GC performance.)

Then:

> But I got an issue here too where the heap dump says it is of ~1GB but when I upload it on Eclipse MAT, it only shows the dump of 11MB. Most of the heavy objects are seen under "unreached objects" section of MAT. Please let me know why a 1GB dump is only showing 11MB size in MAT if you have any idea or have used MAT for analysis.

That is also easy to explain.  The "unreached objects" are garbage.  You must have run the heap dump tool at an instant when the heap usage was close to one of the peaks.

---

Stepping back, it is not clear to me what you are actually looking for here:

- If you are just curious to understand what the monitoring looks like, this is what a JVM normally looks like.
- If you are trying to investigate a performance problem (GC pauses, etc) you need to look at the other evidence.
- If you are looking for evidence of a memory leak, you are looking in the wrong place.  These graphs won't help with that.  You need to look at the JVM's behavior over the long term.  Look for things like long term trends in the "saw tooth" such as the level of the bottom of troughs trending upwards.  And to investigate a suspected memory leak you need to compare MAT analyses for dumps taken over time.

  But bear in mind, increasing memory usage over time is not necessarily a memory leak.  It could be the application of a library caching things.  A properly implemented cache will release objects if the JVM starts running out of memory.